# how to fix Delays in scrolling on my android app

Tags: java, android, image, scrollbar

in my main page app , When scrolling, delayed !
how to fix it ?!

I've compressed images by Photoshop and The total size of all images is <= 100kb and type of images are jpg and png ...

here is my main_layout.xml codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FrameLayout
android:layo`enter code here`ut_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_main" android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/mainscrollView"   >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null" android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/find_my_around" />


                <include layout="@layout/maxoption_first_page" />



                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@null"  >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"  android:tag="persian"
                        android:text="برترین ها در شهر"
                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="19sp"  />

                    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleColor="#ff7584"
                        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
                        app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
                        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                        app:mrl_rippleDuration="400"
                        app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250"  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="70dp" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"  android:tag="persian"
                            android:text="بیشتر  >"
                            android:id="@+id/morebzpbest"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:background="#ffc518" />
                    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
                </FrameLayout>


                <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
                    android:id="@+id/bestcity"
                    style="@style/TwoWayView" android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    tools:context=".BazardanApp" />


                <include layout="@layout/iamhungrybanner"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/foodstation"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@null"  >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"  android:tag="persian"
                            android:text="ایستگاه غذا"
                            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="19sp"  />

                        <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
                            app:mrl_rippleColor="#ff7584" android:id="@+id/ripplemenuop765"
                            app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
                            app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
                            app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                            app:mrl_rippleDuration="400"
                            app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250"  android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="70dp" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"  android:tag="persian"
                                android:text="بیشتر  >"
                                android:id="@+id/morestationfoods"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:background="#ffc518" />
                        </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
                        android:id="@+id/bestmenubzps"
                        style="@style/TwoWayView" android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                        tools:context=".BazardanApp" />

                </LinearLayout>







            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <include layout="@layout/full_screen_loader_by_wifichecker"/>

        <include layout="@layout/custom_actionbar"/>


    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/main_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<include layout="@layout/gettextlayout"/>
<include layout="@layout/signup_notfi"/>
<include layout="@layout/requestfor_signup"/>
<include layout="@layout/requestfor_salecredit"/>
<include layout="@layout/bazardan_id_finder"/>
<include layout="@layout/you_have_gift"/>
```

here is find_my_around.xml codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/findmyaround"
android:layout_height="270dp"
android:gravity="center|center_vertical">
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="#ffffff"
    app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
    app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
    app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
    app:mrl_rippleDuration="400"
    app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/serachmayaround">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgmyaround" android:id="@+id/bgmyaroundimg"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgmyerondshadow" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="100dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center|center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton60"
                android:src="@drawable/mycurentlocation"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="اطراف خود را کشف کنید !"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/textpersia344" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

here is maxoption_first_page.xml codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >
    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="#ffa911"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
        app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
        app:mrl_rippleDuration="400" android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250"  android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/openscanbarcode"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="#ffffff">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgbarcodescanner"  />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/handgqscanner" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="9dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#88000000"  android:tag="persian" android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="اسکن برچسب بازاردان" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="#ffa911"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
        app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
        app:mrl_rippleDuration="400"
        app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/openidbzpfinder"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="#ffffff">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgidfinder"  />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/atbzp" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="9dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#88000000"  android:tag="persian" android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="شناسه یاب بازاردان" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >
    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="#ffa911"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
        app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
        app:mrl_rippleDuration="400" android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250"  android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/openmaybeknow"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="#ffffff">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgidfinder"  />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/meybeknow" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="9dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#88000000"  android:tag="persian" android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="شاید بشناسید !" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="#ffa911"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
        app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
        app:mrl_rippleDuration="400"
        app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250" android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/openmyfinger5km"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="#ffffff">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgbarcodescanner"  />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/locationf3" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="9dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#88000000"  android:tag="persian" android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="۵ کیلومتری انگشتتان !" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="#ffffff"
    app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
    app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="false"
    app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
    app:mrl_rippleDuration="400"
    app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="250" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/amionbzardan"
        android:layout_height="200dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgredcrystal"  />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgmyerondshadowtop" android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="100dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/bgmyerondshadow" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_height="100dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center|center_vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton60"
                android:src="@drawable/mycurentlocation"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:text="آیا هم اکنون در محل بازاردانی هستید ؟!"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"  android:tag="persian" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

please help me , how to fix it ?!

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: edit the question with your activity code

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani , my layout xml is very big ;(

Comment: maybe thats the problem and also, probably your layout and/or the way you are using it is not optimized. I think there is not a solution for your problem, you should dig for problems in your project.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani  , I added xml codes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your are displaying `Bitmaps` in your adapter directly by using `imageView.setImageBitmap`. Instead you should use `UniversalImageLoader`. In `ListView`s bitmaps should not be displayed on `Main thread` instead should be loaded on background threads see the link https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader